# Magento security patch 5344 error

Tags: magento-1.8, install, patches

I am trying to install the newly release security patch for magento 1.8 in my distant server when I get this errors.

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 58.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 69.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 534.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 55.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 143.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 160.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 2834.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej
```

I tried to change the content of files with those [magento-1.9-patch-1533-5344](https://github.com/sashas777/magento-1.9-patch-1533-5344/blob/master/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php)

But always got the same errors.

Is there a way to be fixed

Thank you in advance

ps: My magento version is 1.8.1.0

Comment: Its better to post error messages as text, not as images, that way other people who search for your error can find this post as well.

Answer (score 4):

There are modifications in core files (`app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php` for example and so on), these files are saved with different line endings.

The solution is to compare your current files with original files from Magento 1.8.1.0 distribution and understand why your files got changed. If you believe there should be no any changes in core files, you can simply replace `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php,` 
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php` and so on with original files from Magento 1.8.1.0 distribution and re-run the patch.

In my case it is worked.Please try it this way.Please note, before replacing those files you must keep a back-up of each file.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to version 1.9.1.1 this patch it's already included.

Comment: Upgrading instead of patching is a really good way to put your e-commerce website out of commission. Patching (testing first on a development server) is an expedient to keep your website up and functional in a secure manner until you are sure your template and installed third party modules are tested fully compatible with the  new version. Especially in the template, the difference between 1.8 and 1.9 can be a total show stopper. Any forum dealing with Magento is full of "OMG, I got a notice a new version was out, upgraded and now my website's down" messages.